# `aws configure list` output in JSON or other structured format?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

The `aws configure list` command is useful for dumping the current AWS configuration and debugging problems, e.g. a wayward environment variable or a typo in the config file.

However, it doesn't seem possible to set the output format with `--output` as with most other AWS CLI commands. `--output` simply has no effect, nor does the `AWS_OUTPUT` env var.

Is there a way to obtain this same output in some structured format that is useful for machine parsing? The default tabular format is very easy to read for humans, but a little messy to parse for a computer.

Comment: @Onkeltem you linked to this question instead of the GH issue.

Comment: Thanks @shadowtalker! I couldn't edit the comment, so I deleted it. Here is a new link:
https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/7373